# Map of earth subsurface temperature

Tags: geology, temperature, open-data, geothermal-heat, land-surface-models

I see similar flavours of this question have been asked a few times, but I still don't see a satisfying answer. I am looking for data (maps) of the earth subsurface temperature at a depth sufficient to consider the temperature more or less constant (let's say in a range of ±5% ?). I am looking for data for:

- Latitude: for polar, temperate and equatorial latitudes
- Time of the year: per season or per month
- Time of day: at noon and midnight

Where can I find publicly available (free) data for this?

Comment: ERA 5 Land - Soil Temperature?

Comment: ERA 5 data is only up to soil level 4 (298cm deep I believe) and that shows significant variability with season

Comment: Ah ok - apparently I dont know a whole lot about soil temperature. Thought it was worth a shot. Sorry for the misleading info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a depth of about 1200 km, the temperature can be assumed to be constant, about 5,200° Celsius (9,392° Fahrenheit).

At depths between few hundred meters and some kilometers, the temperature is strongly affected by tectonics/groundwater flow, as represented by the heat flow maps.

You can however extract some informations from the database of the [International Heat Flow Commission (IHFC)](http://ihfc-iugg.org/)

http://ihfc-iugg.org/products